# Sql is fast but when converted to linq it's slow

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

This is fast

```
SELECT Foo,
       count(*)
FROM
  (SELECT Foo
   FROM MyTable
   GROUP BY Foo,
            Bar,
            Baz) AS Subquery
GROUP BY Foo
```

This is fast

```
var query = from fooGrp in
    (from rv in _myRepository.AsQueryable()
        group rv by new {rv.Foo, rv.Bar, rv.Baz}
        into grp
        select grp)
    group fooGrp by fooGrp.Key.Foo
    into grp2
    select new {grp2.Key, Count = grp2.Count()};
query.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count);
```

This is slow, really slow!

```
_myRepository.AsQueryable()
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Foo, x.Bar, x.Baz })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Key.Foo)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
```

I don't understand :(
What is the difference between the two linq expressions? They both return the expected result set.

---

The generated SQL for the first expression (fast) is:

```
SELECT 
    1 AS [C1], 
    [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [Foo], 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C2]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Distinct1].[Foo] AS [K1], 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
            [Extent1].[Foo] AS [Foo], 
            [Extent1].[Bar] AS [Bar], 
            [Extent1].[Baz] AS [Baz]
            FROM [dbo].[MyTable] AS [Extent1]
        )  AS [Distinct1]
        GROUP BY [Distinct1].[Foo]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
```

The generated SQL for the second expression (slow) is:

> Is so long that it exceeds the character limit of this post, so cannot post it :/

Comment: does this answer your question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442891/is-linq-generally-slower-than-a-equal-sql-statement

Comment: What query does the database end up receiving?

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: To me the two linq quries should do the exact same thing. They also produce the same results. But the sequential linq expression take a very long time to execute. I don't understand why

Comment: How are you measuring it?  Are you measuring both the query and `ToDictionary` in the first case?  The query doesn't actually get executed until `ToDictionary` is called.

Comment: Yes it's measured after the ToDict call in both cases.

Comment: take a look at sql profiler and see what the actual call is thats being made,

Comment: included the generated sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out that the LINQ expressions are not identical.

The correct linq expression is:

```
_myRepository.AsQueryable()
    .GroupBy(x => new {x.Foo, x.Bar, x.Baz})
    .GroupBy(x => x.Key.Foo)
    .Select(x => new {x.Key, Count = x.Count()})
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count);
```

I was missing a select, which I didn't expect because in normal SQL you can only select on columns that are in the group by clause. But LINQ does all kinds of magic to get the rest of the columns included, unless you limit it in the select.